# Making seaborn's regplot confidence intervals more transparent (alpha parameter)

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, seaborn, linear-regression

I am having a problem selecting the alpha of sns.regplot because it is not one of the options to customize in the graph (`scatter_kws`, `line_kws`) so I am trying a work around by creating two overlapping plots.

This does not make the confidence interval shading any lighter because `scatter_kws` refers to the scatter points and `line_kws` changes the entire best fit line and shaded confidence interval's alpha.

```
columns = [ 
"col1",
"col2"
]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for col in columns:
    sns.regplot(x=df[col], y=df.y_val, scatter=False, ci = 95,
                scatter_kws={"alpha": 0.3}, label=col)
    
for col in columns:
    sns.regplot(x=df[col], y=df.y_val, scatter=False, ci = 0,
                line_kws={"alpha": 1}, label=col)
    

plt.legend(loc='best', markerscale=5)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

The result is a graph with the same transparency as default and double number of difference colors displayed. The lines are different than the shading.

Answer (score 0):

To set/change the transparency of the regplot shading in ci, you can use `plt.setp(ax.collections[x], alpha=0.x)`. As there was no data, I have used seaborn tips table. collections[0] is for the first item in columns and collections['1] is for the last item there... To showcase this, I have used alpha=0.1 and 0.9. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
df=sns.load_dataset('tips')
columns = [ 
"total_bill",
"size"
]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for col in columns:
    # Removed kws here
    sns.regplot(data=df, x=col, y='tip', scatter=False, ci = 95, label=col)
    
## Using collections
plt.setp(ax.collections[0], alpha=0.1) ## For total_bill
plt.setp(ax.collections[1], alpha=0.9) ## For size

plt.legend(loc='best', markerscale=5)
#plt.ylim(0, 1) ## Not valid for my data
#plt.xlim(0, 1) ## Not valid for my data
plt.show()
```

[image]